# How to using v-slot in v-calendar and not replace the original template

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs-slots

I want to add a checkbox on a v-calendar event.

I'm new to Vuetify.

Here is my code:

```
<v-calendar
    v-model="value"
    :weekdays="weekday"
    :type="type"
    :events="events"
    @change="getEvents"
>
    <template v-slot:event="{ event }">
        <input .../>
    </template>
</v-calendar>
```

[code online](https://codepen.io/jinyao1011/pen/bGOOYMp?editors=1010)

Now the problem is, it will replace the original template which are name and time, how should I keep them all?

Comment: Now I using eventSummary to get data, but there is error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. 
  `<template v-slot:event="{event, eventSummary}">
       <div v-html="eventSummary()" />
        <input />
    </template>`

Comment: figure out： <component :is="{ render: eventSummary }" />